# Node js and Socket.io working fine for localhost but returning 400 for other origins

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

This is my server code:

```
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3001));
  var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
     console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
  });
  var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
  });

  io.set('origins', 'https://desolate-bayou-62509.herokuapp.com/');
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('message', function () {

    console.log("Incoming request");


  }

});
});
```

I have deployed this code in Heroku. This works fine when accessed from localhost. I have deployed the frontend PHP code also in Heroku. Now this Node js code returns 400 error code.

Comment: what is exactly in node error? can you send the 400 error

Comment: request header is: GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1478756314744-0 HTTP/1.1
Host: warm-citadel-18389.herokuapp.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://desolate-bayou-62509.herokuapp.com/
Origin: https://desolate-bayou-62509.herokuapp.com
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: response header is: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://desolate-bayou-62509.herokuapp.com
Date: Thu, 10 Nov 2016 05:38:29 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Via: 1.1 vegur

Comment: Response is {"code":null}